# Need help on how to customize fb generic template with flight search results?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I am working on a travel bot. The user can search and book flight by entering origin,destination along with dates.

I have integrated node.js server and I have an external API to retrieve flight details based on the search.

Everything is working fine,but how do I display the results in a template format (**GENERIC TEMPLATE**).

I have found a similar bot **Skyscanner** which display the search results in a beautiful way.
Like the below one.

[IMAGE TO SKYSCANNER FLIGHT SEARCH RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13NQY.jpg)

They have converted the search results into a image and displaying in a generic template (HOW can we do this ?).

How can I display search results in a template format?
Appreciate Help!

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be an image they are generating and attaching on the fly to the generic template. You could also use the airline itinerary template:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/airline-itinerary-template

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I know they are using the generic template and adding an image url..How can i generate the dynamic image?

Comment: You can use something like the text feature in [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jump) or something like [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/tree/v1.x) for more detailed alterations.

Comment: Ok..I will do some research on the above mentioned links..but can we add dynamic text to images using above libraries?

Comment: Yes, jimp makes it very easy. More complicated with canvas but it also does a lot more